# When does the kernel of a function equal the image?

Tags: linear-algebra

When does the kernel of a function equal the image?
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean a linear transformation or morphism ?

Comment: @user10444 Because of the use of "kernel", I guess so. Note also the tag "linear algebra", which suggests the OP is talking about a linear transformation.

Comment: For an example regarding linear transformations, have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324702/example-of-linear-transformation/324713) question.

Comment: I meant linear transformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, the kernel is the space orthogonal to the rows.  The image however is the column space.  So your kernel equals the image when the rows are all orthogonal with all the columns and the rank is $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for referring in your answer to the general case R^n.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a function which takes $x$ as argument such as $f(x)=y$.

If $x \in \text{Ker} f$ then $f(x)=0 \Longrightarrow f(0)=0$.

If $y \in \text{Im} f$ then $y=f(x) \Longrightarrow f \circ f(x)=0$.

So $\text{Ker} f = \text{Im} f$ if $f(0)=0$ and if for all $x$, $f\circ f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi : V\to W$ is a linear transformation of vector spaces , then $\ker\phi := \{v\in V\mid \phi(v) = 0\in W\}$ and $\textrm{im}\,\phi = \phi(V) := \{w\in W\mid w = \phi(v)\textrm{ for some }v\in V\}$. We see that $\ker\phi\subseteq V$ and $\phi(V)\subseteq W$, so if $V\subsetneq W$ and $W\subsetneq V$, these sets are not even comparable.

If $\phi : V\to V$, then $\ker\phi = \phi(V)$ if $\ker\phi \subseteq \phi(V)$ and $\ker\phi \supseteq \phi(V)$, and I claim that $\ker\phi = \phi(V)\implies\phi(\phi(V)) = \{0\}$. If $\ker\phi \supseteq \phi(V)$, then for all $v\in\textrm{im}\,\phi$, $\phi(v) = 0$. This implies that $\phi(\phi(V)) = \{0\}$.

Moreover, by the rank-nullity theorem, we can say that
$$
\dim V = \dim\ker\phi + \dim\phi(V) = 2\cdot\dim\ker\phi = 2\cdot\dim\phi(V),
$$
so that $\dim V$ is either even or infinite. If $\dim V = n < \infty$, then we can say that $\dim\phi(V) = \dim\ker\phi = n/2$.