# Linear operator such that $N(T)=R(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried hard to find explicit Linear transformation but I couldn't find it. I am doing it from $2$ dimensions. Also by rank nullity theorem I see that dimension of $V$ must be even ($T: V \to V$)

Kindly suggest

Thanks

Comment: See [When does the kernel of a function equal the image?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337209/when-does-the-kernel-of-a-function-equal-the-image)

Comment: @Crostul it does not satisfy 
$T^2=0$

Comment: @crostul I think you mean $T(x,y)  = (y,0)$

Comment: If the range and null space of $T$ are equal (or even if the range is a subset of the null space),then it does satisfy $T^2-=0$.

Answer (score 2):

One example of a linear operator on an infinite-dimensional space, consider the map $T:\ell^\infty\to\ell^\infty$ ($\ell^\infty$ is the space of bounded real or complex sequences) given by
$$ T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots)=(0,x_1,0,x_3,0,\ldots). $$
Then we have 
$$N(T)=\{(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^\infty:x_k=0 \textrm{ for $k$ even\}}=R(T). $$

To get a $2$-dimensional example, consider the restriction of this example to the first two coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be any vector space. Consider a projection $\pi$ followed by an inclusion $\iota$, say $V\oplus V\to V\hookrightarrow V\oplus V$ that kills $V$.

Then ${\rm im}\,{\iota \pi }={\rm im}\,\iota =V\oplus 0$ and $\ker \iota\pi =\ker \pi = V\oplus 0$.